# Swift - How to properly remove blocks from an array when a caller is deallocated?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, closures, observers

I have an array of 'updateBlocks' *(closures)* that I use in a singleton class to notify any observers *(UIViewControllers, etc)* when data updates.

I am wondering what the best way to remove the observer would be so that it is not executed when the observer is deallocated (or no longer wants updates).

Here is my current setup:

**MySingleton Class**

```
var updateBlock: (() -> ())? {
    didSet {
        self.updateBlocks.append(updateBlock!)
        self.updateBlock!() // Call immediately to give initial data
    }
}
var updateBlocks = [() -> ()]()

func executeUpdateBlocks() {
    for block in updateBlocks {
        block()
    }
}
```

**MyObserver Class**

```
MySingleton.shared.updateBlock = {
    ...handle updated data...
}

MySingleton.shared.updateBlock = nil // How to properly remove???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your singleton design has some problems.

Having `updateBlock` be a variable who's didSet method appends a block to your `updateBlocks` array is bad design.

I would suggest getting rid of the updateBlock var, and instead defining an `addUpdateBlock` method and a `removeAllUpdateBlocks` method:

```
func addUpdateBlock(_ block () -> ()) {
   updateBlocks.append(block)
}

func removeAllUpdateBlocks() {
   updateBlocks.removeAll()
}
func executeUpdateBlocks() {
    for block in updateBlocks {
        block()
    }
```

}

If you want to remove single blocks then you'll need some way to keep track of them. As rmaddy says, you would need some sort of ID for each block. You could refactor your container for your blocks to be a dictionary and use sequential integer keys. When you add a new block, your addBlock function could return  the key:

```
var updateBlocks = [Int: () -> ()]()
var nextBlockID: Int = 0

func addUpdateBlock(_ block () -> ()) -> Int {
   updateBlocks[nextBlockID] = block
   let result = nextBlockID
   nextBlockID += 1

   //Return the block ID of the newly added block
   return result
}

func removeAllUpdateBlocks() {
   updateBlocks.removeAll()
}

func removeBlock(id: Int) -> Bool {
   if updateBlocks[id] == nil {
     return false 
   } else {
     updateBlocks[id] = nil
     return true
   }

func executeUpdateBlocks() {
    for (_, block) in updateBlocks {
        block()
    }
```

If you save your blocks in a dictionary then they won't be executed in any defined order.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to get away with not having to use add/remove functions, but it was sloppy. I ended up using something like this to help track the callers better:
    func addUpdateBlock(_ block: @escaping () -> (), sender: AnyHashable) {
        updateBlocks[sender] = block
    }

Answer (score 0):

That's a very confusing API. From the client's point of view you are setting the value of a single block. But the implementation actually adds that block to an array and then immediately calls that block. And why would you force-unwrap the optional block?

Since you want to support several observers and provide the ability to remove observers, you really show have `addBlock` and `removeBlock` methods in your singleton. Then the API and its functionality are clear.

The trick is how to provide an API that lets an observer tell the singleton to remove a specific block. I would model the API after how it is done in the `NotificationCenter` class where the `addBlock` method returns some generated token. That token is then passed to the `removeBlock` method.

The implementation would likely be a dictionary keyed on the token and the value is the block. The token can be a `UUID` or some other generated, unique opaque value. That makes the `addBlock` and `removeBlock` methods simple. Then the `executeBlocks` method would iterate the values of the dictionary and call those blocks.

Here's one possible implementation:

```
class UpdateBlocks {
    static let shared = UpdateBlocks()

    var blocks = [UUID: () -> ()]()

    private init() {
    }

    func addBlock(_ block: @escaping () -> ()) -> Any {
        let token = UUID()
        blocks[token] = block

        return token
    }

    func removeBlock(_ token: Any) {
        if let token = token as? UUID {
            blocks[token] = nil
        }
    }

    func executeBlocks() {
        for (_, value) in blocks {
            value()
        }
    }
}

let token = UpdateBlocks.shared.addBlock {
    print("hello")
}

UpdateBlocks.shared.executeBlocks() // Outputs "hello"

UpdateBlocks.shared.removeBlock(token)

UpdateBlocks.shared.executeBlocks() // No output
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this instead:

    func addUpdateBlock(_ block: @escaping () -> (), sender: AnyHashable) {
        updateBlocks[sender] = block
    }